# Redirecting I / O from cmd.exe using CreateProcess () and CreatePipe()

Tags: c++, winapi

My problem is that I can't get output from the command line using pipes.

*My task: "Redirect the command input stream to cmd.exe | output the result of the cmd.exe command to the main process."*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;



#define deffBuffSize 1024




int funSC() {

    HANDLE writeToCL, readFromCL, writeToProcess, readFromProcess;
    char lpCmdLine[] = "cmd.exe /k ipconfig";
    STARTUPINFOA siA;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piApp;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr;
    ZeroMemory(&secAttr, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
    ZeroMemory(&siA, sizeof(STARTUPINFOA));

    secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    if (CreatePipe(&readFromCL, &writeToProcess, &secAttr, 0) == 0) {
        cout << "Create pipe error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(writeToProcess, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        cout << "SetHandleInformation error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    if (CreatePipe(&readFromProcess, &writeToCL, &secAttr, 0) == 0) {
        cout << "Create pipe error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(readFromProcess, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        cout << "SetHandleInformation error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    siA.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);
    siA.hStdInput = readFromProcess;
    siA.hStdOutput = writeToProcess;
    siA.hStdError = writeToProcess;
    siA.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;


    if (CreateProcessA(NULL, lpCmdLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &siA, &piApp) == 0) {
        cout << "CreateProcessA error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        CloseHandle(readFromProcess);
        CloseHandle(writeToProcess);
    }
    
    DWORD dRead = 0;
    char chBuff[deffBuffSize];
    bool bSuccess = FALSE;
    memset(chBuff, '\0', deffBuffSize);
    string outStd;
    bSuccess = ReadFile(readFromCL, chBuff, deffBuffSize, &dRead, NULL);

    cout << "bSuccess: " << bSuccess << endl;
    cout << "GetLastError: " << GetLastError() << endl;


    cout << "Message: " << chBuff;
    //CloseHandle(writeToCL);
    //CloseHandle(readFromCL);
    CloseHandle(piApp.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piApp.hThread);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int result = 0;
    result = funSC();
    system("pause");
    return result;
}
```

When I execute ReadFile (), I get the result.
ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE (109) - The pipe has been ended.
As I understand it, the pipe is closed at the end of the recording => Question: "Why should CreateProcess() execute "ipconfig" and not output it to an overridden output stream."

I read MSDN, tried to use the ready-made code (for understanding), but this did not lead to a positive result.

**Help me please, I will be very happy if I understand how to solve this problem =)**

PS: I cannot "close" the console window, because I must have a valid directory (For example: cd *anyFolder*) If I close the process, I will lose the directory to which the user passed.

**This is how I tried to read from the pipe**

```
for (;;) {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(readFromCL, chBuff, deffBuffSize, &dRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || dRead == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Message: " << chBuff;
        }
     }
```

This endless loop didn't read anything.

P.S : *This is the output of a running program, but it only outputs one line of the "ipconfig" command*

[image: This is the output of a running program, but it only outputs one line of the "ipconfig" command]

Comment: As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, two notes: It lacks a [mcve] and it isn't clear whether your issues are specific to cmd.exe or whether they occur on any console application.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt In front of you, you see the real code that I need. As for other console applications, I have not done tests with other than cmd .exe

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Or what did you mean?

Comment: That code can't be used to _reproduce_ your issues, it doesn't even have a `main()` or the like and thus doesn't compile. It's your task to also remove anything unnecessary from the code to post here, before you even type that question, as a means to reducing the scope of the problem.

Comment: @BerserkHacker Compare to [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I fixed my mistake =)

Comment: @dxiv Я I used this tutorial to understand, but the result of the function ReadFromPipe ()  was an empty string.

Comment: @BerserkHacker I didn't follow all of it, but you are missing a `secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;` for one thing.

Comment: @dxiv This line is just above CreateProcessA()

Comment: @BerserkHacker Right, that's *after* `secAttr` has been used in the `CreatePipe` calls already.

Comment: @dxiv I moved the initialization strings of secAttr before using CreatePipe(), but the result is still negative.

Comment: `SetHandleInformation(writeToProcess, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT)`, set the last parameter to `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` as well. And put the initialization of `secAttr` before calling `CreatePipe`. Then it works for me.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Hooray, it helped, but in msdn about the 3rd parameter they say that it can be left NULL if the 2nd parameter specifies a flag.

And for some reason I only wrote down one line from the output of the "ipconfig" command

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have added a screenshot to the code

Comment: It might be worth developing a pipe reading function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the error of ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE(109) caused by the cmd.exe exit unexpectedly. According to the sample [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output):

> The parent process uses the opposite ends of these two pipes to write
> to the child process's input and read from the child process's output.
> As specified in the STARTUPINFO structure, these handles are also
> inheritable. *However, these handles must not be inherited. Therefore,
> before creating the child process, the parent process uses the
> SetHandleInformation function to ensure that the **write handle for
> the child process's standard input and the read handle for the child
> process's standard output** cannot be inherited.*

You have set the other two handles to be un-inherited, so that cmd.exe exits without an available standard handle.

Set the pipe side of child process instead:

```
if (!SetHandleInformation(readFromCL, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
    cout << "SetHandleInformation error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
if (!SetHandleInformation(writeToCL, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
    cout << "SetHandleInformation error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
```

The issue of content size may because you need to wait for the output from cmd.exe. Add function like: `Sleep(1000)` before `ReadFile` Simply could solve it. Then, you could choose the most suitable method to synchronize the input and output of the two processes. Such as read in a for loop:

```
for (;;) {
    memset(chBuff, '\0', deffBuffSize);
    bSuccess = ReadFile(readFromCL, chBuff, deffBuffSize, &dRead, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess || dRead == 0) {
        break;
    }
    else {

        cout << chBuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me a lot.

Comment: `Sleep` doesn't sound like the solution to any problem presented in this topic

Comment: Yes, Thx for pointing out. But it is just used to prove the cause of the problem, OP can choose the most suitable method to synchronize the input and output of the two processes.